# Java connect to FileMaker pro 16

Tags: java, filemaker

I try to establish the connection between Eclipse and FileMaker - I want to access the database there, but I get this error message

```
(com.filemaker.jdbc.FMSQLException: [FileMaker][FileMaker JDBC] (802): Unable to open file
).
```

According to official document (https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fm16_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf), I believe I import Jdbc.jar and fmjdbc.jar into my java path, as I do this when I connect to MySQL.

Here is part of my code for establishing the connection.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    try {

        Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName("com.filemaker.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbaseURL, username, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Could anyone give me some clues or hints about how to get the connection? My java version is 1.8 and I use FileMaker Pro 16.

Comment: FileMaker file has to be open, user who connects should have "Access via JDBC" extended privilege enabled for FileMaker file.

Comment: According to official document (https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fms/en/index.html#page/fms/hostdb_verify.html), I open the file (database) already.

Comment: Did you check user then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

802 error means:

> Unable to open file. This error can be caused by one or more of the
>   following:
>   • Invalid database name
>   • File is closed in FileMaker Server
>   • Invalid permission

If the file is definitely open, there's probably a missing permission. Enable XDBC access for the account you are using to connect.